# passport with express: serialization issue with custom authentication method

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript, passport.js

```
   #set up passport
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'}, (email, password, done) ->

    User.findOne({ email: email }, (err, user) ->
      console.log("findone")
      if err?
         console.log "error"
         return done(err)
      if not user
        console.log("incorrect username")
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' })
      if password isnt user.password
          console.log "NOT"
          return done(null, false, {message: "Incorrect password" })
      console.log "BUT YESS"
      done(null,user)
    )
))


 passport.serializeUser((user, done) ->
          done(null, user._id)
    )

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) ->
          User.findById(id, (err, user) ->
             done(err, user)
          )
    )
```

I am using the LocalStrategy example as found at http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/

Now, my problem is that if I enter a wrong password, or an incorrect username, I get an error `Error: failed to serialize user into session`.

In fact, in my serializeUser function, `user` is `false`. This probably is because the code literally returns false as the second parameter above:
`return done(null, false, {message: "Incorrect password"` })

But this is from the docs! So what am I doing wrong? Why do I have a serialization problem when parameters are incorrect? When parameters are ok (username and password correct), I can login without problems

EDIT: Upon comment by @robertklep here is how I use the authentication function. Indeed, because I need to route differenly depending on role, I use the passport custom method (this detail added to title of question):

```
app.post '/login', (req, res, next) ->
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) ->
    return next(err) if err?
    return res.redirect('/login', { message: req.flash('Access denied')}) if not user?
    req.logIn user, (err) ->
      if err?
        console.log "err! " + err
        res.redirect("/", { message: req.flash(err)})
        return
      if user.role is "admin" or user.role is "auditor"        
        res.redirect("/dashboard")
      else
        res.redirect("/start") 
  )(req, res, next)
```

Comment: Hmm perhaps it depends on how you call the Passport authentication methods, because for me, `serializeUser` isn't even called when the authentication fails (by passing `false` to the callback much like what you're doing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.post '/login', (req, res, next) ->
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) ->
    console.log "authenticate callback"
    if err?
      console.log "err in authenticate callback"
      return next(err)
    if not user
      console.log "User NOT in auth callback"
      req.flash("Accesso no otorgado", info.message)
      return res.redirect('/login')
```

I rewrote a bit the authenticate function.
Instead of `if not user?`, the solution is to use `if not user` (no question mark!), as the "user" returned is just a boolean set to false when things went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy( function(username, password, done) {
    user.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {

  if (err) { return done(err); }

 //check for incorrect username
  if (!user) {
    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
  }

  //incorrect password for the selected username
   if (user.password != password) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
    }
  return done(null, user);

});
}
));



 app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {

passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user,info) {
        if (err) {
        //console.log(info);
            return next(err); }

if (!user) { 
        console.log(info);
        return res.redirect('/login'); }

req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); 
        }

            return res.redirect('https://www.google.co.in' );
    });

    })(req, res, next);

 });


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});


passport.deserializeUser(function(login, done) {
    user.findById(login._id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
    });
});
```